# Redirect Old URLs with htm Extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have moved to php software that creates SEF URLs.  But my site has been around a long time and there are many Not Found errors that come in for old URLs that have the htm extension.  Is there a way to direct any URL with the .htm extension to, say, the home page of the site?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. This is very easy to find on the 'net, a query for `.htaccess redirect url` should give you everything you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect any URL that ends with `.htm` or `.html` to the homepage and if you remove `l?` it will redirect only `.htm`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Keep in mind if you have other rules on your `.htaccess` it may conflict with those rules and I would have to see it as the way its done might need to be different to work without conflicting with your current rules.